# Why JS design pattern snippet not work in sublime

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

Following sublime snippet is not working:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
        (function ($) {
            var defaults = {};

            function NAME(element, options) {
                this.config = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
                this.element = element;
                this.init();
            }

            NAME.prototype.init = function () {
            };

            $.fn.name = function (options) {
                new NAME(this.first(), options);
                return this.first();
            };
        }(jQuery));

]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>jqp</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.js</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Also it would be of great help if someone can show me how to use custom parameters in the snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
(function (\$) {
    var defaults = {};

    function ${1:name}(${2:element}, ${3:options}) {
        this.config = \$.extend({}, ${2:defaults}, ${3:options});
        this.element = element;
        this.init();
    }

    ${1:NAME}.prototype.init = function () {
    };

    \$.fn.${1:name} = function (options) {
        new ${1:NAME}(this.first(), options);
        return this.first();
    };
}(jQuery));
]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>jqp</tabTrigger>
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

This should do the trick. `$` is a special character, so you have to escape it with a `\`. Also, I removed your extra indentation and added tab stops to allow for custom parameters. You have to use the `${#:PLACEHOLDERNAME}` notation to create a tab stop at a certain word. You would replace `#` with your number based on what order you want the tab stops to go, and you would replace `PLACEHOLDERNAME` with whatever you want the placeholder value to say. You can read more about Sublime Text Snippets [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html).

Comment: The `<scope>` is just for deciding which type of files the snippet will work for. Right now, it is set to `source.js` which means that the snippet will only be active for JavaScript files. If you want the snippet to work for all file types, (.java, .html, .css, etc) you can just remove or comment out the `scope` tag.